# NGINX Load Balancer and Multiple Virtual Web Servers On Same Computer?

Tags: nginx

I'm going to be deploying software that I'm developing as a SaaS product in the future.  I would like to create a "startup" network that can simply be expanded as the number of customers increases **without having to re-architect the network design.**  I understand the `load balancer>web servers>application servers>database servers` architecture.

My question is, "Can I place an NGINX load balancer and multiple virtual NGINX Web servers on the same Linux server?"  I am asking this question so that I can appropriately design my startup network infrastructure without having to invest in separate Linux NGINX load balancer and NGINX Web server computers during the startup phase of my business.  I realize that if my software is successful that I will need to add dedicated Web servers as the demand on my network grows.

I know that I can use a single NGINX Web server without a NGINX load balancer during startup.  But I want to design my startup network so that I don't have to mess around with installing, configuring, and testing a new NGINX load balancer while I'm experiencing a (hopefully) significant increase in SaaS customers.  My thinking is that if the NGINX load balancer and Web servers have already been configured and tested on a single Linux server, then as customer demand grows its a simple matter of adding new NGINX Web server computers, pointing the already-running NGINX load balancer at the new NGINX Web servers, and decommissioning the virtual NGINX Web servers.

Comment: yes @bill vallance, take a Look on proxmox ve (lxc) , docker or other similar virtualisation

Comment: @djdomi, is this a common scenario with NGINX?  By that I mean running the load balancer and virtual web servers on the SAME Linux computer?  Any issues you've come across that I should be aware of?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: yes @'Bill Vallance' virtualisiation is a common scenario, i ran an nginx as frontend and run 10 lxc Container for serving content to nginx, plus wach domain has its own Container